# Is there any usage of implicit functions with several parameters in Scala?

Tags: scala

Implicit functions with several parameters are allowed, that is:

```
implicit def it(path: String, category: String):Iterator[String] = ...
```

But can the Scala compiler do something useful with it? If not, why doesn't it complain?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, the compiler can do something with it if you ask for such an implicit.

```
def f(implicit ev: (String, String) => Iterator[String]) = ...
```

Comment: Wonderful scala, if not as implicit converter, then as implicit argument )

Comment: @yura If you look into Scala Language Specification, you'll see that these two things are actually unified. Looking up implicit conversion from `A` to `B` is equivalent to looking up implicit parameter of type `A => B`. So implicit conversions and implicit parameters are roughly the same thing under the hood.